Transitivity of subset relation (proof using hypothetical syllogism).
This question is about a comparatively formal approach to a simple theorem. The theorem says, If $ A\subseteq B$ and $ B\subseteq C$ then,  $ A\subseteq C$. Symbolically, $ (A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq C)\implies A\subseteq C$. Most probably we can use the hypothetical syllogism $ (A\implies B\land B\implies C) \implies (A\implies C)$  concept and prove it.
We know,
$$A\subseteq B \iff (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x\in B)$$
And,
$$B\subseteq C \iff (\forall x)(x \in B \implies x\in C)$$
Therefore,
$A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq C \iff  (\forall x)((x \in A \implies x\in B) \land (x \in B \implies x\in C ))  \iff  (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x\in C ) \iff A\subseteq C$
So, we have proved $ (A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq C)\iff A\subseteq C$. But the theorem says the transitive relation is conditional (if-then) not equivalent.
The question might seem silly but I can't find where is the supposed mistake in the proof. Can anyone help me with this?


Therefore,
$A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq C \iff (\forall x)((x \in A \implies x\in B) \land (x \in B \implies x\in C ))  \iff  (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x\in C ) \iff A\subseteq C$

The mistake is $(\forall x)((x \in A \implies x\in B) \land (x \in B \implies x\in C )) \iff  (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x\in C)$.
You assumed $(A\Longrightarrow B\land B\Longrightarrow C)\iff(A\Longrightarrow C)$.
For example, $A$ and $C$ can be the predicate $x\in\{1\}$. $B$ can be the predicate $x\in\{2\}$. Note that $A\Longrightarrow B$ and $B\Longrightarrow C$ are both false but $A\Longrightarrow C$ is true.

I think I have just found an issue. The syllogism is actually a conditional relation. So, is this correct now?$A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq C \iff  (\forall x)((x \in A \implies x\in B) \land (x \in B \implies x\in C ))  \implies  (\forall x)(x \in A \implies x\in C ) \implies A\subseteq C$

Seems to be good now.
